# Change the value of a label continuously

Tags: javafx, label, scenebuilder

I'm trying to add my system time to my application, to do so I've set a label that I want to change continuously with my value.
I'm using JavaFx and scenebuilder.
I started with that little code but I don't know how to put my variable dateString into my label date.

```
 SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy" );
 SimpleDateFormat h = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm");

 Date currentTime_1 = new Date();

 String dateString = d.format(currentTime_1);
 String heureString = h.format(currentTime_1);  

 @FXML
 private Label heure;

 @FXML
 private Label date;
```

Could you please help me with this.

Edit :
Here is my entire controller class :

```
`package application;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.chart.BubbleChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class Controller {
     @FXML
     private void demarage_trajectoire (ActionEvent event){

     }

     @FXML
     private void demarage_suivi (ActionEvent event){

     }

     @FXML
     private void demarage_carto (ActionEvent event){

     }

     @FXML
     private void demarage_test (ActionEvent event){

     }

     @FXML
     private void demarage_trajectoire_accelerée (ActionEvent event){

     }

     @FXML
     private BubbleChart trajectoire_theorique;

     @FXML
     private Label valeur_gisement_theorique;

     @FXML
     private Label valeur_site_theorique;

     @FXML
     private Label heure;

     @FXML
     private Label date;

     @FXML
     private Label valeur_gisement;

     @FXML
     private Label valeur_site;

     @FXML
     private Line gisement;

     @FXML
     private Line site;

     @FXML
     private Label tension1;

     @FXML
     private Label tension2;

     @FXML
     private Label tension3;

     @FXML
     private Label tension4;

     SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy" );
     SimpleDateFormat h = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm");

     Date currentTime_1 = new Date();

     String dateString = d.format(currentTime_1);
     String heureString = h.format(currentTime_1);
     date.setText(dateString);

}
```

`

Comment: `date.setText(dateString);`?

Comment: I actualy tried that but it tells me that it's not working on e(fx)clipse

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: I have the red cross on the left and it says that I have 4 differents syntax errors only on that line.Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
 Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName
 Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName
 Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration

Comment: Those are compile errors; you just need to fix them. It's just syntax... Post the whole method where you are trying to execute that code if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I've put my entire controller class but there is basically nothing on my code that's the reason why I don't understand where is my problem here.

Comment: That statement is not even in a method. Of course it won't compile like that.

Comment: Thanks I'm a bit stupid ! I thought it could work without method Java is quite new for me, I still learning. Thanks a lot. Just need to try if it works.

Comment: Work it get the time but only once it do not update continuously

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AnimationTimer to execute some code like the one give by James in order to continuously update your label. But I'd recommend to do this update at a lower frequency than the standard interval of the AnimationTimer.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific because the code provide by James do not work whith my code. Thanks

Comment: @David: You need to add some information about that. James' code should be working, given your current problem description. It's unlikely that you get a satisfying answer without adding more info.